# How to upload files in parallel from client to Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, load-balancing

Using the `hadoop fs -put` command the data goes in sequential way into the cluster.

But how to upload data parallely from client side to HDFS cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `hadoop fs - put` works sequentially. Use `distcp` command(distributed copy).

```
hadoop distcp file:///home/user/path /user/path
```

`distcp` is implemented as a MapReduce job where the work of copying is done by the maps that run in parallel across the cluster. There are no reducers. Each file is copied by a single map, and `distcp` tries to give each map approximately the same amount of data by bucketing files into roughly equal allocations. By default, up to 20 maps are used, but this can be changed by specifying the `-m` argument to `distcp`.

See manual [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html).
Also see [this blog post](https://hadoopadminexp.blogspot.in/2016/07/distcp-to-copy-files-from-local-file_18.html).

Also you can run shell commands in parallel using ampersand (`'&'`) at the end:

```
hadoop fs - put src_file tgt_file &
hadoop fs - put src_file2 tgt_file2 &
```

Comment: It will depend somehow on the infrastructure and where the data source data is located. distcp doesn't provide high parallelism if the input data resides on a local FS (a non-distributed store) and not on HDFS.

Comment: @U880D added more info